# In orthographic view I always see the vertices behind the view as well ("x-ray") despite x-ray being turned off. Why is that?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, orthographic

In orthographic view I always see the vertices that should be hidden (i.e. behind the view, x-ray) as well, even though x-ray is toggled off.

I have followed a youtube tutorial and changed all relevant settings to milimeter, could this cause the problem?

[image]

**EDIT: The suggestion below that it could be z-fighting turned out to be right. I had to lower the "end value" in the viewport view settings from 5 million to 5000 for the problem to go away.**

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>  while hovering over 3D Viewport or Toggle X-Ray icon just after Show Overlays and before Wireframe Viewport Shading mode icons in the Header of the 3D Viewport:

[image]

to toggle X-Ray mode.

[image]

Comment: Ok but that way I see the vertices underneath. Thats what I dont want.

Comment: Have you tried it? If you toggle it off, then you don't see verts on the other side. Is it different when you try it? Could you share an image of what happens?

Comment: Maybe you have extreme scale or extreme camera/viewport clipping values and see z-fighting...

Comment: I have the problem that no matter if I toggle x-ray off or on, my orthographic view is always showing the vertices behind (as well as those in front, i.e. x-ray view). It does change the boldness of the edges a bit but its always see through. I have set up mm instead of the standard meters in my settings. Is that maybe the cause for this?

Comment: Seems like you are right that its z-fighting. I changed the end value to 5000 and now the problem is gone.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some screenshots of the problem. If you change units, it is possible that camera or viewport clipping planes are not set adequately. If you set mm in Blender, you should work in mm scale as well. If you set mm and then attempted to work with objects several meters in size, problems are possible.

Comment: Hello I have edited the question. If you want to edit your answer to reflect the correct answer (z-fighting) I could accept it as the answer to the question posted.